# measure power consumption of dc motor

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, dc-motor

I have a 12v dc motor and when I run it with load it is drawing 10amp and now I want know what is my power consumption. Theorically equation is Watt = V·I but I know current but I'm not sure voltage. Because when I charged battery average value is 13.5 Volt and while I driving dc motor I check voltage of battery and ıt's write 12.5 volts. So while driving my dc motor what is my real power consumption 13,5 V · 10 A = 135 W or 12,5 · 10 A = 125 W?

Comment: For the motor itself you would use the latter.  The decrease in battery voltage under load is due to the power the battery is using with it's internal resistance, which is separate.  You might also want to look up the difference between true, reactive and apparent power if accuracy is important in your application since the motor is inductive.

Comment: @KH thanks for your information